# Redirect domain to WWW

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to make a URL change whenever clients access my website with `example.com` to `wwww.example.com` I have used .htaccess for this but it works not correct.

Because now `a-z0-9.example.com` wil also redirect to `www.example.com`, I want this only works for `example.com`  than redirect to `www.example.com`

.HTACCESS

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.eample.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: It looks correct. But you should escape the period. `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]`

Comment: The problem is it works also for subdomains, it redirects the subdomein to http://www...

Comment: That's what I'm trying to tell you. That rule alone is not going to work for subdomains. Do you have anything else in your .htaccess file. The rule is correct except for not escaping the period. Make sure you're not caching anything and clear your browser cache too.

Comment: no only this lines inside my .htaccess

Comment: Did you try another browser? As Panama Jack said, this line should work. Browser also cache redirects, maybe your browser cached the redirects before you changed the .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Make another .htaccess for `a-z0-9.example.com` with the code bellow:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} a-z0-9.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.a-z0-9.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

I think this will work.

Good Luck!